# handleChange is not a function , React Native Picker

Tags: react-native

From `context.js` I have passed the function to `SetupForm` to update the picker value. But it's not working.

SetupForm.js -

```js
    const SetupForm = () => {
    const {quiz, handleChnage, handleSubmit, error} = useGlobalContext();
    return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>HHH</Text>
          </View>
 
          {/* category */}
          <View>
            <Text>Category</Text>
            <View>
              <Picker
                label="category"
                selectedValue={quiz.category}
                onValueChange={e => handleChnage(e)}>
                <Picker.Item label="Sports" value="sports" />
                <Picker.Item label="History" value="history" />
                <Picker.Item
                  name="politics"
                  label="Politics"
                  value="politics"
                />
              </Picker>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>{error && <Text>Can not Generate Questions</Text>}</View>
          <Button title="Start" onPress={handleSubmit} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    );
    };
```

handleChange function looks like:

```js
    const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e);
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setQuiz({...quiz, [name]: value});
    };
```

After changing the `picker` value it shows that `handleChange` is not a function. Here I'm passing value from `Picker`.

Comment: Maybe because you misspelt the `handleChange` to `handleChnage` which you're passing from `useGlobalContext` in your `setupForm.js`.

Comment: Thanks @ShoaibKhan , it's for my typing mistake